# Hold Spinner value for next tab

Tags: android, memory, tabs, spinner

I want the selected value from a spinnner to be kept in memory or temp table or anywhere, so that it can be used on next tab.
I watched lot of tutorials, but didn't find any solution.
I've the following code (it gives me toast message only; I populate the spinner from a database):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customers);
    addFromDB();
    select_cust_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.select_cust_name);
}

private void addFromDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_db);
    resultsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, 1, null);
    // ////////////These are using to add the values to database
    myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " (" + _id
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + cust_name
            + " TEXT , " + cust_add + " TEXT)");
    myDB.execSQL("insert into tbl_customer(cust_name, cust_add) values ('Fool', 'FF' );");

    final Cursor c = myDB.query(SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    char _idColumnIndex = (char) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
    char cust_nameColumnIndex = (char) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cust_name");
    char cust_addColumnIndex = (char) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cust_add");
    adapterForSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterForSpinner
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapterForSpinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
                Toast.makeText(
                        parent.getContext(),
                        "Customer is "
                                + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        insert(selected);
```

Thanks in advance.

here is my log:

```
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/tab.layout/databases/db_sales, table = tbl_customer, query = SELECT * FROM tbl_customer
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at tab.layout.Customers.addFromDB(Customers.java:63)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at tab.layout.Customers.onCreate(Customers.java:40)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at tab.layout.MyTablayoutActivity.SetupTabs(MyTablayoutActivity.java:48)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at tab.layout.MyTablayoutActivity.onCreate(MyTablayoutActivity.java:20)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 11:29:31.743: E/Cursor(10155):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what does this function `insert(selected);` do? If you are able to Toast it, then you should be able to save it as well! To pass it to next tab, save it in some global variable.

Comment: i tried insert(selected) to add value to trunk table..but it gives me error,

Comment: what is the error? write the logcat lines here. also, indicate which line in the code has error. Write the above code in a try-catch block, so that you get the error in detail.

Comment: As Pallavi said. You have the value you need. You can save that to the database or store it in SharedPreferences so that you can easily access it anywhere. Though, that may not be entirely necessary. I am not 100% familiar with tab controllers in Android, but I assume that you can pass information to the parent (by interface or otherwise). Then the controller could send that to other tabs where necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple options...

**Global Variable**

Declare it in your main activity

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    public static String myString;  // declare global variable
}
```

Sett from anywhere...

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
         Main.myString = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
}
```

Then you can just use Main.myString in whatever your next activity/tab/fragment is.

You didn't say how you were doing the tabs (if they were a new activity or not) so another possible way is to pass it through an intent extra.

**Pass in intent**

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("Selected", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
    CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

then in the new activity retrieve it like so:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String selected = extras.getString("Selected");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to use the selected string to view on next tab.. i use **txtEmps.setText(txtEmps.getText()
      + String.valueOf(Customers.getSelected()));
          txtEmps=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.select_cust_name);** to display it on final tab..but it gives me force close error

Comment: Set the global variable as I showed above, then in your new tab use `txtEmps.setText(Main.myString)`.  Note you need to change the class and variable names to match whatever you set them up as in your app.  Also, `txtEmps=TextView)findViewById(R.id.select_cust_name);` needs to be BEFORE `txtEmps.setText(Main.myString)` or you will get an NPE

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is related to database helper class. can u paste the method you have written for selecting contents from the table...

Comment: why have written insert(selected).?  this is actually a method which is not there in your class.

Answer (score 0):

or in your method close the cursor and also db at the end
   db.close();
if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
 cursor.close();
}